# Error when using development time IIS support

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Update: this bug has been fixed for a while now

I installed Visual Studio 2017.3 yesterday and was trying to used the new Development time IIS Support feature. I think I encountered a bug, and I was wondering if anyone knows a workaround this bug. When I used it with a new project it works fine most of the time. By most of the time, is that I think it is broken sometimes depending on the where the project is located/state of cached data, etc.

Sometimes I get an error **"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name"**. That's the entire error. No log files, no extra information.

- I tried to enable the feature for an existing project I am working
  on, it got that error.
- I tried adding a new web project in a new solution it worked fine.  I tried adding a new web project in the same solution as my project, it didn't work.
- I deleted all temp files, all bin obj and .vs folders and .user files in the
  solution. Same problem.
- I deleted temp folder, visual studio user profile data, and restarted the PC same problem.
- I tried again in the same solution with the project not having '.' in the name, it worked.
- I did some modification to the project that was working and tried to launch again I got same error.
- I reverted all changes so that the project was back to the "empty project" state, still same error.
- I removed the project. Exited visual studio, deleted all temp/.vs/.use/bin/obj files. Then restarted and added the project again, it worked.
- I restarted VS and tried to relaunch it didn't work.
- The aspnet core version seems to be not related to the bug. I had the problem with projects targeting 1.1 and 2.0 and also had the feature working for both versions.

So obviously this is a bug in VS2017.3. Since even if I am doing something wrong I should at least get an error explaining what I do wrong not an ArgumentNullException message. I already made a bug report. I am wondering if someone knows a workaround thing bug.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is the project name?  What kind of asp.net core website it is?  What version?

Comment: project name is Bubi.Web. Tried BubiWeb worked at first then didn't work later.

Comment: And the version doesn't seem to matter. I am having the problem with 1.1 and 2.0. Also have it working in other cases with both.

Answer (score 3):

Update: This bug has been fixed for a while now.

After some investigation and with help from a helpful member of Microsoft's Visual Studio Team, I found that Visual Studio was failing at the point where it grants folder read access to the IIS App Pool account. The method that gets the App Pool account name was returning null, and when that null value was passed to the System.Security.Principal.NTAccount class constructor, the ArgumentNullException is thrown.

A workaround that fixed the problem for me, was changing the App Pool to any other App Pool, trying to launch, then changing it back to the original/desired App Pool.

Answer (score 0):

- First You Must Update Visual studio with visual studio Installer and Launch the Visual Studio installer.
- And Select the Development time IIS support component and Modify.
- Wait For Download is Processing
- The component is listed as optional in the Summary panel for the ASP.NET and web development workload.
- Then you Create New Project Again
- Problem Solved.